# Press ENTER robot framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework, enter

When I use Press Keys    locator    ENTER, instead of pressing ENTER it writes “ENTER”. There is no search button to press just textbox. Please help.

Comment: Can you show us your `code` ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer! Instead of ENTER should be \13

Press Keys    Location    \F13
(ASCII code for the key we want to use)

Answer (score 0):

Press Keys   |   {locator_here}   |   ENTER

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
Press Keys  <locator>   RETURN      # Pressing "ENTER" key to element.
```

or

```
Press Keys  <locator>   \\13
```

More details at - https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Press%20Key